# Multiple language Not work only AlertDialog

Tags: android

Multi language Not work only in AlertDialog. Its work well all other function . i added following code.

```
   protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    SharedPreferences mPrefs = getSharedPreferences("FmRadio2", MODE_PRIVATE);
    String selectedlanguage = mPrefs.getString("language", "en");

    Locale locale = new Locale(selectedlanguage);
    Locale.setDefault(locale);
    Configuration config = new Configuration();
    config.locale = locale;
    getBaseContext().getResources().updateConfiguration(config, getBaseContext().getResources().getDisplayMetrics());
```

change language dialog:

```
  language_one.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener() {
        @Override
        public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView, boolean isChecked) {
            if(isChecked){
                Locale locale = new Locale("en");
                Locale.setDefault(locale);
                Configuration config = new Configuration();
                config.locale = locale;
                getBaseContext().getResources().updateConfiguration(config, getBaseContext().getResources().getDisplayMetrics());

                SharedPreferences.Editor editor = getSharedPreferences("FmRadio2", MODE_PRIVATE).edit();
                editor.putString("language", "en");
                editor.apply();

                languagealert.cancel();
                themeischanged = true;
                Intent i = getBaseContext().getPackageManager().getLaunchIntentForPackage( getBaseContext().getPackageName() );
                i.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
                startActivity(i);

            }
        }
    });

    language_two.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener() {
        @Override
        public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView, boolean isChecked) {
            if(isChecked){
                Locale locale2 = new Locale("ta");
                Locale.setDefault(locale2);
                Configuration config2 = new Configuration();
                config2.locale = locale2;
                getBaseContext().getResources().updateConfiguration(config2, getBaseContext().getResources().getDisplayMetrics());

                SharedPreferences.Editor editor2 = getSharedPreferences("FmRadio2", MODE_PRIVATE).edit();
                editor2.putString("language", "ta");
                editor2.apply();

                languagealert.cancel();
                themeischanged = true;
                Intent i = getBaseContext().getPackageManager().getLaunchIntentForPackage( getBaseContext().getPackageName() );
                i.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
                startActivity(i);

            }
        }
    });
```

Language not work following AlertDialog ..some time ( when click option menu close app completely).

```
    public void exitapp(){
    AlertDialog.Builder exitappbuilder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
    exitappbuilder.setPositiveButton(getResources().getString(R.string.menu_exit_app), new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
            finish();
        }
    });
    exitappbuilder.setNegativeButton(getResources().getString(R.string.review_now), new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
            
            Reviewnow();
        }
    });
    AlertDialog dialog = exitappbuilder.create();
    dialog.show();
}
```

all other place all i used getResources().getString its working fine but this alartdialog not (if reopen app completly)work some time otherwise its work